# How to encrypt a pickled file in Python?

Tags: python, encryption, nlp, cryptography, pickle

I have a ml model that uses a vectorizer. This vectorizer contains sensitive data and is stored using pickle as a .pkl file.

How can I encrypt this pkl file, so that it requires a key to decrypt?

I tried using the below code for encryption.

```
def encrypt_file(filepath, key):
    f = Fernet(key)
    with open(filepath, "rb") as file:
        # read all file data
        file_data = file.read()

    # encrypt data
    encrypted_data = f.encrypt(file_data)

    with open(filepath, "wb") as file:
        file.write(encrypted_data)


def decrypt_file(filepath, key):
    f = Fernet(key)
    with open(filepath, "rb") as file:
        encrypted_data = file.read()
        
    decrypted_data = f.decrypt(encrypted_data)
    return decrypted_data
```

When I use the function on a txt file it works. The problem is that the pkl file does not seems to be encrypted, as it can still be used without decryption.

Comment: the function you're showing is for *decryption*, not *encryption*

Comment: Also, assuming your encryption code is similar, you're not actually en/decrypting the file. Instead, you're en/decrypting the contents of the file into an object in your program. You have to then explicitly write that transformed content out to the file to finish the process.

Comment: My encrypt and decrypt functions both work correctly when encrypting/decrypting txt files. So I don't believe there is anything wrong with the function.
@President James K. Polk

Comment: Sorry about that. I posted the wrong function. But do you know why pkl and txt files would behave differently when I try to encrypt them? Because the txt file clearly does get replaced with an encrypted version using this method. Thank you in advance @Edo Akse

Comment: The problem is that there is not a complete example here. When I fix all the bugs in your code the code runs perfectly, the pickled file is correctly created, written, encrypted, decrypted, and unpickled.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get it to properly encrypt/decrypt a pickle file neither. It gave me distorted data on decryption.

So I did the next thing, switch libraries. [pyAesCrypt](https://pypi.org/project/pyAesCrypt/) does exactly what you want, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

See this sample code:

```py
import pickle
import pyAesCrypt


def create_pickle(picklefile):
    data = {"data": "random"}
    with open(picklefile, "wb") as outfile:
        pickle.dump(data, outfile)


password = "please-use-a-long-and-random-password"
picklefile = "somefile.pkl"
picklefile_enc = f"{picklefile}.aes"
create_pickle(picklefile)

# encrypt
pyAesCrypt.encryptFile(picklefile, picklefile_enc, password)
# decrypt
pyAesCrypt.decryptFile(picklefile_enc, f"2_{picklefile}", password)

with open(f"2_{picklefile}", "rb") as infile:
    print(pickle.load(infile))
```

**output**

```py
{'data': 'random'}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for posting your solution. One question: Do you have to create a secondary decrypted file? Is it not possible to read the dictionary on the fly?

Comment: you can encrypt streams, so with some logic you can encrypt without using the intermediate file. Take a look at the documentation for [pyAesCrypt](https://pypi.org/project/pyAesCrypt/)

Answer (score 2):

Fernet works simple enough, just need to handle the data correctly (ergo, get to bytes before encrypt/decrypt, as Fernet handles bytes).

```
import os
import pickle

from cryptography.fernet import Fernet


'''
Generate a key using Fernet.generate_key(), then store on environment variable or file.
Such as 

os.environ['ENCRYPTION_KEY'] = Fernet.generate_key().decode()

or

with open('my_secret.key', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(Fernet.generate_key())
os.environ['ENCRYPTION_KEY_PATH'] = 'my_secret.key'
'''


def load_key(fp: str = None) -> bytes | None:
    if fp:
        with open(fp, 'rb') as f:
            return f.read()
    if key := os.getenv('ENCRYPTION_KEY'):
        return key.encode()


def load_pickle(fp: str) -> object:
    if key := load_key(os.getenv('ENCRPYTION_KEY_PATH')):
        fernet = Fernet(key)
        with open(fp, 'rb') as f:
            return pickle.loads(fernet.decrypt(f.read()))
    with open(fp, 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)


def save_pickle(obj: object, fp: str):
    if key := load_key(os.getenv('ENCRPYTION_KEY_PATH')):
        fernet = Fernet(key)
        with open(fp, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(fernet.encrypt(pickle.dumps(obj)))
        return
    with open(fp, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(obj, f)
```

You will need to `pip install cryptography` for this to work.

You will need Python 3.8+ for the Walrus operators to work, or break the `if` statements out appropriately.

```
key = load_key(os.getenv('ENCRYPTION_KEY_PATH'))
if key:
...
```